# Ruby on Rails: NoMethodError undefined method `get_yaml' for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, prawn

I tried to deploy a non public project but sometimes when tried to use 
report pages (based on prawn) I have this problem:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `get_yaml' for #<String:0x7fdecffd3738>):
```

The piece of code is:

```
report_content = report.draw(report_content.get_yaml)
```

Someone know: where are get_yaml come from?

Thanks.

Comment: what you want to do with `get_yaml`?

Comment: Looks like `report_content` is a String, which does not respond to `get_yaml` (unless some library is adding it via monkey patching). What is `report.draw` expecting, yaml?

Comment: I found:   `def get_yaml
    YAML::load( @contents )
  end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method #get_yaml is not a part of of the standard Ruby library, although #to_yaml is defined if the *yaml* library has been loaded.  #get_yaml, if it exists, is defined by the application or by some library that the application is loading.

Comment: Thanks @wayne-conrad!